# Boundary of Closure

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. I know it is not generally true $\partial A=\partial{\overline {A}}$ for every $A\subset X$. I found it is true if $A$ is a closed ($A=\overline A)$or regularly open set($A=A^{o}=(\overline A)^{o}$). Any other subset of $X$ with different properties satisfying $\partial A=\partial{\overline {A}}$? 
 Is it generally true $(\partial A)^o=\emptyset$ for all $A\subset X$? Thank you.
 Notation: 
$\partial A=$ Boundary points of $A$ 
$\overline A=$ Closure of $A$
$A^{o}=$Interior of $A$

Comment: Since $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$ and $\partial \overline{A} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{\overline{A}^c}$, you can see that you need to look for sets for which the containment $\overline{\overline{A}^c} \subset \overline{A^c}$ is strict.

Answer (score 6):

It is not generally true that boundaries have empty interior.  In $\mathbb R$ (with the usual topology), the boundary of $\mathbb Q$ is all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Indeed $\partial \mathbb{Q}  = \mathbb{R}$, but $\partial \overline{\mathbb{Q}}  = \partial \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$. So this is an answer to both questions.

Answer (score 0):

As for all possible equations $\xi_1(A)=\xi_2(A)$ where the $\xi_i$ are each formed by composing the boundary, closure, interior, and complement operators any number of times in any order the answer to your first question “Any other subset of $X$ with different properties satisfying $\partial A=\partial{\overline {A}}?$” turns out to be “no” up to trivial substitutions such as $A^{o}=X\setminus\overline{(X\setminus A)}.$

The proof is long. Most of it appears in a paper I will be posting within the next several weeks (my last-minute literature search is what brought me here).

Also, note that

$$\partial A=\partial{\overline {A}}\iff A^{o}={\big(\,\overline A\,\big)}^{o}\iff{\big(\,\overline A\,\big)}^{o}\subseteq A\iff\partial A\subseteq X\setminus{\big(\,\overline A\,\big)}^{o}.$$